# VS Inline temporary variable suggestion breaks Async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2017, task, inline

Can someone explain following behaviour?

Normal async function that works as expected when called from async event handler:

```
private async Task SomethingAsync()
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
            tasks[0] = this.SomeTaskOne();
            tasks[1] = this.SomeTaskTwo();
            await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        }
```

After VS inline suggestion (Quick Action) that breaks :

```
    (new Task[2])[0] = this.SomeTaskOne();
    (new Task[2])[1] = this.SomeTaskTwo();
    await Task.WhenAny(new Task[2]);
```

And when i run it i get:

> The tasks argument included a null value. Parameter name: tasks'

I'm not sure how inlining works, but shouldn't the outcome be the same?
From my understanding it's just hiding the local variable.

Comment: do you mean by "After VS inline suggestion" that the little lightbulb told you to break your code? Because that's broken code. If VS told you to do that, then you need to open a connect with them detailing how to reproduce.

Comment: Well yeah, Quick Actions.

I was thinking about opening issue , but i'm not sure what is causing issue.

Comment: I agree, VS can mess up.  Also try avoiding just blindly refactoring using tools like these.  It can become a cargo cult situation.  I like this version more anyway

public static Task MyMethodAsync()
 {
  return Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { SomeTaskOne(), SomeTaskTwo() });
 }

Comment: I' m not using refactoring tools extensively , just basic stuff like converting prop to full prop. But i'm curious why this is happening.